# Architecture of adding Azure Blob Storage to non-cloud ASP.Net/Silverlight application

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, azure-storage

I'm having trouble getting started, or finding a relevant example, using Azure Blog Storage from a non-Azure asp.net and silverlight application.
I have a Silverlight browser app, hosted in an asp.net application.  I need to add the ability to save and retrieve images between Azure and the site.  I don't want to migrate the entire site to Azure... I just want to use it for storage.

My questions, making it difficult to get started are...

- Do I need to add a Windows Azure Project to my solution?
- If I use the Azure project, do I just need a web role? Is that integrated into the existing asp.net site, or is it in addition to?
- Should I just be using the Windows Azure Storage Service REST API?
- Is there a good example of a similar setup.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a reference to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll and use it. That library is redistributable, but you'll probably want to get it from the SDK. (I don't think there's a separate download available.)